# Is it possible to trigger explicit intent using model-viewer?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I've got a model-viewer in my app and I want to create an action button for it (in AR). It was easy to do for iOS,
I did it by adding the parameters in the url like so: .../model.usdz#title=title... etc.
Is there a way to do the same thing for android?
The only docs page I found was [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/scene-viewer), tried doing it according to this syntax, but it didn't show.

```
<a href="intent://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0?file=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf?mode=ar_only#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.ar.core;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=https://developers.google.com/ar;end;">Avocado</a>;
```

Comment: See https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/743